# Exclude password protected posts from wordpress page

Tags: wordpress

Can anyone explain how I can change the below code to exclude posts that are password protected? I know I can do so with an if statement within the while statement but I want to exclude them from the WP_Query point.

```
$pq = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => $ptype, 'showposts' => $pshow ));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it happen with a `post_where` filter, just before you execute your query:

```
function getNonPasswordedPosts(){    
    // Add the filter to exclude passworded posts
    add_filter('posts_where', 'excludePassworded');

    // Query for the posts
    $pq = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => $ptype, 'showposts' => $pshow ));

    // Remove the filter so that other WP queries don't exclude passworded posts
    remove_filter('posts_where', 'excludePassworded');

    // iterate over returned posts and do fancy stuff    
}

function excludePassworded($where) {
    $where .= " AND post_password = '' ";
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: You should also probably remove the filter after the query using remove_filter('posts_where', 'excludePassworded');